# Userform Closes when i close another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i need some advice regarding my issue i made a userform with a bunch of buttons on each button it simply opens a file within our shared folder

my issue is that when i open my userform for the first time and then hit a button the other excel file opens but it won't let me close it via X button unless i close the userform so what i did was i hide the userform briefly then show it again any advice on this case?

secondly issue is that when i close another excel file that i open using the userform macro the userform closes along with it ? i don't have any application.quit on my code and wb.close so this is really eating me

last case is when i close my userform it doesn't let me open it for the 2nd time nothing happens on the third time the excel file appears even thought i set the workbook open to application.visible=false.  any advice on this? since the application.quit closes all the excel file opens and i need the other workbook to stay open even thought i want to close my userform

any advice will be gladly apprciatted

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo abc


...\2023 Q3 - ....xlsx", Password:="...2023", UpdateLinks:=0

    
Me.Hide

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim filePath As String

    filePath =...\2023 Q3 - ....xlsx"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks(Dir(filePath))
        If wb.ReadOnly Then
        MsgBox ("File In Use - Read Only Copy")
        End If
        

Dim newForm As New ChTools

newForm.Show vbModeless

wb.Activate



Done:

    Exit Sub
    
abc:

    MsgBox "File Not Found"

End Sub


Private Sub Main_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

'Unload Me
'
'Dim wb As Workbook
'Dim filePath As String
'
'
     filePath =...\... Trackers\CH Tool.xlsm"
'    Set wb = Workbooks(Dir(filePath))
'
'  If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
'   wb.Close
'  Else
'   End If

'Me.Hide

Application.Visible = True


end Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()

Me.Hide
Application.Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).WindowState = xlMinimized


End Sub
```

i want my userform to open files without affecting other excel files

Comment: Likely to much code here - can you boil it down to the minimum required to reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: sorry about that all shortened but to sum it up its userform issue

Comment: I'm not sure the 'shortened' code allows us to understand or replicate your problem ... suggest reading this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and updating your code again

Comment: I agree that you have too much useless code in the code you shared.  At the same time, I think you are leaving out some important code that I would like to see.  Is there any code in the other workbooks that you open? Particularly in the open and close event handlers?  Are you sure that the user form closed and didn't just go to the background?  You are showing it modeless, so I would expect it to go to the background.  Why modeless?